# ffmepg Video Encoding got a error with "invalid plane data size"

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

ffmpeg version:4.0.3; video size: 611G; Duration:01:34:03

- encoding command is:

ffmpeg -i 2131.MOV -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 600k -vf scale=640:-1 small.mp4

- video info:

```
ffprobe version 4.0.3 Copyright (c) 2007-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)
  configuration: --enable-shared --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xca7ac0] overread end of atom '�mak' by 2 bytes
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xca7ac0] overread end of atom '�swr' by 3 bytes
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '04487162221cb76b0a4465037f4a3d7d.MOV':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2024-04-16T19:59:27.000000Z
    make            : Atomos
    make-eng        : Atomos
    encoder         : ShogunSumo - 9.11Cn 
    encoder-eng     : ShogunSumo - 9.11Cn 
    com.atomos.hdr.gamut: Rec709
    com.atomos.hdr.gamma: Rec709
    com.apple.proapps.image.{TIFF}.Make: Atomos
    com.apple.proapps.image.{TIFF}.Model: ShogunSumo
    com.apple.proapps.image.{TIFF}.Software: 9.11Cn
    timecode        : 00:00:00:00
  Duration: 01:34:03.86, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 929321 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 4 channels, s32 (24 bit), 4608 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2024-04-16T19:59:27.000000Z
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: prores (apcn / 0x6E637061), yuv422p10le(bt709, progressive), 3840x2160, 924704 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 5k tbn, 5k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2024-04-16T19:59:27.000000Z
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 422
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2024-04-16T19:59:27.000000Z
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 2
```

- log with error:

```
frame=166986 fps=9.8 q=24.0 size=  350976kB time=00:55:39.46 bitrate= 861.0kbits/s speed=0.196x    
frame=166991 fps=9.8 q=24.0 size=  350976kB time=00:55:39.56 bitrate= 861.0kbits/s speed=0.196x    
[prores @ 0x94f840] invalid plane data size
    Last message repeated 85 times
[prores @ 0x94f840] ac tex damaged 1024, 1024
[prores @ 0x94f840] invalid plane data size
    Last message repeated 1723 times
frame=166997 fps=9.8 q=24.0 size=  350976kB time=00:55:39.68 bitrate= 860.9kbits/s speed=0.196x    
[prores @ 0x94f840] invalid frame header
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
```

how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Corrupt input data.

Comment: can you tell me more about it?,is that means I can not encoding the video?  how can I solve it

Comment: Yes, those corrupt frames will be discarded.